# Pass a url return from JS function into href

Tags: javascript, html, url

I'm still new to JS and HTML5

So I have a URL that I store in a var

```
var Base_URL = "https://www.mywebsite.com/info?username";
```

Which is linked to a Database that has access to a **username** value that can contain spaces.

I parse this url into a function

```
function removeSpaceURL(url) {
var update = url.split(' ').join('%20');
return update;
}
```

It is not the best way I know but it works good enough for its purpose.

Where I'm stuck is that I want to return the **update** into a href reference so I can click it.

```
    <p><a href="" onclick="removeSpaceURL(BASE_URL);return false;" >Survey</a></p> 
<script>
   var Base_URL = "https://www.mywebsite.com/info?username";

function removeSpaceURL(url) {
    var update = url.split(' ').join('%20');
    return update;}

</script>
```

When I try it on JSfiddle, I get the following error:

> {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: The correct thing is to have `Base_URL` be a correctly-formed URL in the first place, which it isn't if there's a space in the username part of it.

Comment: Why wait until the click to fix it? Why make clicking the link fix the URL and then not follow the link?

Comment: The values of username from the databse might contain a space (ex. John Smith). Unfortunately i do not have access to the code in order to restrict that option. therefor the need for me to extract the info and parse it so that when i get the url it is not cut of at every space

Comment: Well, whoever does have access to the code creating `Base_URL`, *that's* where this should be fixed.

Comment: I totally agree and despite trying to get in touch with them, i have to come up with this solution to by pass it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct thing is to have `Base_URL` be a correctly-formed URL in the first place, which it isn't if there's a space in the username part of it.

But assuming you're stuck with it, it's quite simple to set an attribute on an element:

```
<p><a id="target-link" href="">Survey</a></p> 
<script>
   var Base_URL = "https://www.mywebsite.com/info?username";
   document.getElementById("target-link").setAttribute(
        "href", encodeURI(Base_URL)
   );
</script>
```

Note using `encodeURI` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002829/pass-a-url-return-from-js-function-into-href/42002910?noredirect=1#comment71182114_42002910) by [emiliopedrollo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2295606/emiliopedrollo) rather than a simplistic replacement of just spaces. But that said, if *parts* of the URI have already been encoded correctly and only the username is the problem, `encodeURI` might double-encode things. So if you just want to replace spaces:

```
document.getElementById("target-link").setAttribute(
    "href", Base_URL.replace(/ /g, "%20");
);
```

Also note that `return false` from an `onclick` on a `a` element will prevent the link from being followed, so I've left off the `onclick` entirely.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you ! From what i m guessing from your answer, the **setAttribute(_parameter_)** enables me to set the target of my script to an attribute inside of a tag?

Comment: @emiliopedrollo: Yeah, very good point, though with a malformed URI (partially encoded correctly, partially not) it could introduce other problems...